# replacing a class in jquery, stops the element doing the desired action

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list of categories, you can only select one. There is a class for the selected one, and when a different filter is selected, the selected one loses its selected class, and goes back to non-selected. However, once this has occurred I can no longer click on the element to add the class.

```js
$('.bpcustomers_not_selected').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.bpcustomers_selected').removeClass('bpcustomers_selected').addClass('bpcustomers_not_selected');
  $(this).removeClass('bpcustomers_not_selected').addClass('bpcustomers_selected');
});
```

```css
.bpcustomers_filter li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.bpcustomers_not_selected:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.bpcustomers_selected {
  color: #2585fe;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bpcustomers_filter">
  <li class="bpcustomers_selected" data-value="0">ALL</li>
  <li class="bpcustomers_not_selected" data-value="1">Under £1000</li>
  <li class="bpcustomers_not_selected" data-value="2">£1000-10,000</li>
  <li class="bpcustomers_not_selected" data-value="3">£10,000-25,000</li>
  <li class="bpcustomers_not_selected" data-value="4">£25,000-50,000</li>
  <li class="bpcustomers_not_selected" data-value="5">Over £50,000</li>
</ul>
```

If you click on anything except ALL, then try and click on ALL again it won't select.

How is this fixed?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using `$('.bpcustomers_not_selected').on('click'` instead of `$('.bpcustomers_not_selected').click` when you have dynamic content.

Comment: I guess it's the different syntax for doing the same thing

Comment: You apply the click event to all `.bpcustomers_not_selected`, but in your JSFiddle the ALL doesn't have this class on load, hence why there is never a click-handler applied to it

Comment: thanks, on() worked fine, I was thinking about trying it

Answer (score 1):

Since the **ALL** does not originally have the `bpcustomers_not_selected` class and you are adding it dynamically, you need to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in `bpcustomers_filter`, like this:

```js
$('.bpcustomers_filter')
  .on('click', '.bpcustomers_not_selected', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.bpcustomers_selected').removeClass('bpcustomers_selected').addClass('bpcustomers_not_selected');
    $(this).removeClass('bpcustomers_not_selected').addClass('bpcustomers_selected');
  });
```

```css
.bpcustomers_filter li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.bpcustomers_not_selected:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.bpcustomers_selected {
  color: #2585fe;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bpcustomers_filter">
  <li class="bpcustomers_selected" data-value="0">ALL</li>
  <li class="bpcustomers_not_selected" data-value="1">Under £1000</li>
  <li class="bpcustomers_not_selected" data-value="2">£1000-10,000</li>
  <li class="bpcustomers_not_selected" data-value="3">£10,000-25,000</li>
  <li class="bpcustomers_not_selected" data-value="4">£25,000-50,000</li>
  <li class="bpcustomers_not_selected" data-value="5">Over £50,000</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```html
$('.bpcustomers_not_selected').click(function(){
```

to

```js
$('.bpcustomers_filter > li').click(function() {
```

This error is caused because the ALL don't have the .bpcustomers_not_selected class which you used as the jquery selector.

Comment: i cant, because I need to identify the classes for other actions

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you bind your onClick event, the ALL doesn't have the targeted class. hence the onClick will never fire for that LI.

I suggest giving every item a class which you can then use to target the clicks and just append and remove a "selected" class on the click.

e.g.

```
$('.all-my-lis').click(function(){
    $('.all-my-lis').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```